# How to merge two decode statements within one.?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm selecting let's say user_name from two tables if the following conditions match

```
user_name=DECODE (krt.user_name,' ',' ', RTRIM (krt.user_name))
user_name=DECODE(length(krt.user_name),10,krt.user_name,16,substr(krt.user_name,6,10))
```

How to merge these two statements.?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want the user name to be `NULL` when the length is neither 10 nor 16?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `CASE` statement:

```
with krt as (
  select ' ' user_name from dual union all
  select '1234567890' from dual union all
  select '1234567890123456' from dual
)
select case
         when krt.user_name = ' ' then krt.user_name
         when length( RTRIM (krt.user_name)) = 10 then  RTRIM (krt.user_name)
         when length( RTRIM (krt.user_name)) = 16 then substr( RTRIM (krt.user_name),6,10)
       end
  from krt
```